# Return column with varying values depending on change points

Tags: sql-server

I'm fairly new to Microsoft SQL Server, so maybe this is very simple yet I just don't have the experience to pull from.

The data I have is similar to the first three columns shown (A, B, C). I want to use those columns to return the data in the yellow highlighted column (D). Basically, I'm trying to show all values of a variable from the current week onward, including when there are change points of the variable. The value of the variable should continue forward in time until the value of the variable changes (column C).

Thanks in advance.

[image: See image describing the situation]

Comment: This looks like a gaps and island question. Have you tried anything at all? If so, what did you try, if not, you should really try yourself first. The volunteers at SO also really appreciate if you provide sample data as `text`. Images are much harder to work with, as we have to rekey all your data if we want to test a solution; which will put us off answering your question.

Comment: I have tried a solution that involves case statements and the LAG function, but to no avail yet. Thank you for your suggestion - I will follow that protocol next time!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.*, COALESCE(SQ.NewValue, T1.StartingValue) FROM YourTable T1
           OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 T2.NewValue FROM YourTable T2 
                               WHERE T1.Week <= T2.week AND 
                                     T2.NewValue IS NOT NULL
                                  ORDER BY T2.Week DESC) SQ
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make Column D a correlated sub-query that gets the most recent previous value of C that is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

One method, which doesn't need 2 table scans is to use a CTE to create a "group number" and then the `OVER` clause with a `MAX`:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,0.5,NULL),
                (2,0.5,1),
                (3,0.5,NULL),
                (4,0.5,NULL),
                (5,0.5,0.8),
                (6,0.5,NULL)) V(WeekNo, Starting, New)),
CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(New) OVER (ORDER BY WeekNo ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM VTE)
SELECT WeekNo, Starting, New,
       ISNULL(MAX(New) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.Grp),Starting) AS Result
FROM CTE
ORDER BY WeekNo;
```